# WCF Ria classlibrary in a console

Tags: wcf-ria-services

I have a WCF Ria classlibrary (using EF)  which is referenced in web project . Then a silverlight app is linked to the  Web project and this works perfectly.

Now I am trying to reuse the WCF Ria classlibrary  in a console application. I added a  refernce to the WCF ria class library from console and try to do operations. But nothing is happening.

Am I doing something wrong? Is the WCF RIA  supposed to consume only Silverlight clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out. We can expose WCF ria using SOAP endpoints.
In order to do this,

step 1

- make  changes in the web.config file of the application where we
  host the ria service.

```
...............
<sectionGroup name="system.serviceModel">
  <section name="domainServices" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServicesSection, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
```

....................

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <domainServices>
     <endpoints>
       <add name="soap"
            type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.SoapXmlEndpointFactory, 
                  Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, 
                  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
       ...
     </endpoints>
   </domainServices>
   ...
 </system.serviceModel>

........
```

Step2 - Add reference to the dll

```
Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting on the wcf ria services.This dll is a part of WCF RIA Services toolkit
```

Now the The service is ready to use . Usually the service will have a URL like this 
http:// nameofyourserver:port/ClientBin/NameOfYourSolution-Web-NameOfYourDomainService.svc

step 3 -  Add service reference at the client side just like  any other WCF service.

More details on how to use the WCF RIA exposed via SOAP in a non-silverlight app is here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2010/03/29/silverlight-4-ria-services-ready-for-business-exposing-wcf-wsdl-services.aspx